# Extending NSMutableURLRequest with custom fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutableurlrequest

I want to add additional fields to `NSMutableURLRequest` (for exapmle `NSString` value `requestID`) in order to determine correct handler for request when `NSURLSession` completes it.

Is it legal to create a custom `NSMutableURLRequest`'s subclass to add specific fields? Apple documentation has no additional information about `NSMutableURLRequest` subclassing.

**UPDATE:**
I discovered that `NSMutableURLRequest` subclassing is not the best idea: background `NSURLSession` can't create download task using my custom subclass object: method `downloadTaskWithRequest:` always returns nil. I think this problem related with `mutableCopyWithZone:` that called by `NSURLSession` when it creates download task with request's copy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that if Apple does not provide any warning of subclassing a class, then you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

I had no problem creating the task with my subclass, but when I tried to access my custom field from task.originalRequest I discovered it is a NSMutableURLRequest, not my custom subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of extending `NSMutableRequest`, I would Suggest create basic N/w call handler which would accept your custom parameter.

In this class itself you can use `NSMutableRequest` to create findal Request with given paramters.
This class can be used application wide to serve you response / data for any request.